# Eureka Forms: Hiding rows without empty spaces in the table

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am trying to use Eureka for a complex input form with a search bar, where the search query filters cells based on their titles and hides those that don't match it. The problem I faced is that when I hide the cells there is an empty space:

[image]

```
 if !searchText.lowercased().isEmpty {

for row in rows {

    if let title = row.title {
        if !title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
            **row.baseCell.isHidden = true**
        } else {


        }

    }`
```

How do I update the form to remove that empty space without actually removing the cells?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that it can be done using:

```
row.hidden = true
row.evaluateHidden()
```